Google OAuth not working on Heroku - "Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
I'm building an app in Next.js with NextAuth and the Google OAuth provider.
I have currently deployed the app both:

on Vercel for development
and on Heroku for the production app

To be able to connect to the app using Google OAuth, I went the Google cloud console and did the following:

In the OAuth consent screen settings, I added app_name.vercel.app and app_name.herokuapp.com to the authorized domains.

Also, I went in the credentials settings, created an OAuth 2.0 Client ID.



Then I added app_name.vercel.app and app_name.herokuapp.com in the Authorized JavaScript origins,
And I added https://app_name.vercel.app/api/auth/callback/google and https://app_name.herokuapp.com/api/auth/callback/google in the Authorized redirect URIs.

For the vercel deployment it's working fine. I can connect and I'm redirected to the app. However, for the heroku deployment, at https://app_name.herokuapp.com/, I get the following error from Google Auth when trying to connect:
You can’t sign in because this app sent an invalid request. You can try again later, or contact the developer about this issue. Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of this app, see error details.
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

And when I click on "error details", I get the following explanation:
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
You cannot log in to the app because it does not comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.
If you are the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details: redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google

Why is it talking about localhost:3000? Does anyone knows what's happening and how to solve it?
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
NOTE: In the OAuth Google Provider for NextAuth, I tried to add
redirect_uri: "https://www.app_name.herokuapp.com/api/auth/callback/google",
With this, I don't get the Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch and I can connect with Google, but I'm then redirect to http://localhost:3000 so I'm not logged in my app.

Check the request details in your Image it tells you exactly what redirect URI to add.
It needs to match exactly

but on the image it's saying that I should add redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google. So the issue is that it's trying to redirect to http://localhost:3000 instead of my heroku app for some reason

The issue is your application is running on local Host so that's the redirect uri

no actually the problem is that my application is NOT running on localhost! That's why it's weird... I get this error message with my application running on heroku, at https://app_name.herokuapp.com/

You need to understand that google does not make up the redirect uri it adds to the return image.    That IS the redirect uri your application is telling Google that it wants the data returned to.   All you need to do is add it in the google cloud console.   Your application is running Localhost even if you dont think it is the redirect uri is automatically created based upon where your application is running and how its configured.   The image shows http://localhost:3000 that IS where your application is running.

Hi Linda, I really appreciate you trying to help but how can my app be running on localhost:3000?  I have nothing running on my port 3000, and if I take another device, like my iPhone, navigate to app_name.herokuapp.com and try to connect with google I get the same error message.
So yes, if I add this "localhost:3000/api/auth/callback/google" to the Authorized redirect URIs in the google cloud console, I do indeed get rid of this error. But after logging in, I'm redirected to localhost:3000 and not to my application at app_name.herokuapp.com, so this doesn't solve my problem :/

You're right that google does not make up the redirect uri, so that's why I think the issue is in the way the app is hosted on heroku (because on vercel everything works fine), but I don't know exactly what the problem is there (my environment variables don't contain anything about "localhost:3000").

I cant help with Heroku but try googling "heroku how to change localhost" there's loads of answers.
